# How to open dialer screen/make a phone call using GWT phonegap

Tags: java, gwt, cordova, phone-call

I have a GWT application that is using phonegap (Cordova) to make it into a mobile app.

I want to make a phone call in a native way (be it Android or iOS) how can I do this using GWT APIs. http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/313383/Using-GWT-and-PhoneGap-for-complex-mobile-applications seems to give some pointers but it seems too complex to understand

useful information in that link is

`Access basic functions through special URIs
URI scheme  Meaning
href="tel:555-5555"
 href="mailto:someone@somewhere?subject=something...&body=some.text..."

 href="sms:555-5555?body=some.text..."

 href="mailto:someone@somewhere?subject=something...&body=some.text..." 
**Meaning**
Open the dialer application to call the given phone number.
Open the SMS application to send an SMS with the given body text to the provided phone number.
Open the email application to write a message to the provided email account with the given subject and body. There are more options, such as sending cc or bcc copies.
In the sample application, I added a couple of hyperlinks to show how to call someone or how to send an SMS. Of course, by using GWT DOM manipulation methods, you could set up the URIs dynamically, instead of hardcoding them as I did in the sample.`

Can someone tell me how to make a phonecall/open dialer using GWT

Answer (score 0):

[Make a phone call programatically using Libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867433/make-a-phone-call-programatically-using-libgdx?noredirect=1#comment38634652_24867433)

Look if this answer is good for you.

I'm using libgdx and I'm trying to make able the app to do phonecall using both android and iOS. But, if in Android is simple doing this using the native, in the other hand I cannot find a way to do the same for iOS in java without using objective c.