# Make a phone call programmatically using Libgdx

Tags: ios, libgdx

I'm creating an app using libgdx.
In the contact page I would like, as for the email
(
Gdx.net.openURI("mailto:cippa@lippa.com");
), give the chance to made a phone call by clicking on the phone number.

Is this possible using libgdx?
Or I have to do this twice, using first Android and then iOS?

(Like in this question:
[How to make a phone call programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816683/how-to-make-a-phone-call-programmatically))

---

EDIT

How is possible to make a phone call programmatically in JAVA for iOS?
Because for Android is clear, simple and done, but for iOS, without using Objective-C?

Comment: You do have to do it differently for iOS and Android. Just create an interface for it, and pass the platform-specific implementation of the interface into your game's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As for the edited question (IOs phone call in Java), I haven't tested this code, but I think it should work:

```
UIApplication.getSharedApplication().openURL(new NSURL("telprompt://" + number));
```

Comment: How can I extract contacts from the phone book? Do you know? Does it work on both Android and iOS?